# How to concisely build up a Scala List from dependent elements?

Tags: list, parsing, function, scala, recursion

I want to build a `List` of `Foo` objects, each constructed by reading off a byte array starting from where the last `Foo` finished. Given that the only state needed when building are the contents so far and the number of bytes read, I was thinking of doing this by the repeated application of a function transforming a smaller `List` into a larger one. At each step the current `List` is passed as a parameter (and maybe the amount of bytes read so far to avoid re-parsing for this) and returned with an element appended. As this seems a pretty straightforward way to build up a `List` I was interested but unsuccessful in finding library functions that I could use for this. The following is the imperative example of what I am trying to do, I would like to make the functionality in `bytesToList` stateless and more concise:

```
def bytesToList(bytes: Array[Byte]): List[Foo] =
{
  var numBytesRead = 0
  var listToBuild = List[Foo]()
  while (numBytesRead < bytes.length)
  {
    listToBuild ::= new Foo(bytes, numBytesRead)
    numBytesRead += listToBuild.last.bytesRead
  }
  listToBuild
}

class Foo(bytesToRead: Array[Byte], startReadingAt: Int)
{val bytesRead = Random.nextInt(bytesToRead.length)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't split the array up beforehand, you need to use explicit recursion, something like:

```
def bytesToList(bytes: Array[Byte], n: Int = 0): List[Foo] = 
  if (n >= bytes.length) Nil
  else {
    val foo = new Foo(bytes, n) 
    foo :: bytesToList(bytes, n + foo.bytesRead)
  }
```

I don't know how may Foos you're expecting to have, but if it's more than a thousand or so, it's a good idea to make this tail recursive to avoid blowing up the stack (hint: add an extra parameter for the output, default value `Nil`).

Answer (score 3):

My quick and dirty? solution is here:

```
//some random source for bytes
def bytes(count: Int): Stream[Byte] = {
    var byteArray: Array[Byte] = new Array(count)
    Random.nextBytes(byteArray)
    (for {i <- (0 to count-1) } yield byteArray(i)).toStream
} 

class Foo(b1: Byte, b2: Byte, pb: (Byte, Byte)) {
    def this(bytes4foo: Array[Byte]) = this( bytes4foo(0), bytes4foo(1), (bytes4foo(2), bytes4foo(3)) )
    def sizeOf: Int = 4
    override def toString = "Foo("+b1+", "+b2+", "+pb+")"
}

def bytesToList(source: Stream[Byte]): List[Foo] = {
  val afoo = new Foo(0,0,(0,0)) // ~ static Foo.sizeOf
  def moreFoo(next: Stream[Byte]): List[Foo] = {
    if (next == Stream.Empty) Nil
    else new Foo(source.take(afoo.sizeOf).toArray) :: bytesToList(source.drop(afoo.sizeOf))
  }
  moreFoo(source)
}
```

Test it with:

```
bytesToList(bytes(20)) mkString "\n"    
//> res1: String = Foo(-73, 63, (-14,107))
               //| Foo(-61, 105, (-124,-44))
               //| Foo(117, 79, (-79,-17))
               //| Foo(-84, -116, (13,-3))
               //| Foo(93, -110, (30,36))
```